# Vibration in scrollview while scrolling

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll, scrollview

I am adding views to scroll view dynamically. According to the data coming from web service I create view by adding images and label and add it to scroll view. The problem is that while scrolling the images vibrate which should not happen. I am not understanding the reason. Please help with it

Comment: Can you up a video of your problem ?
Even a bit of your code can be useful !

Comment: Do you mean that the scrolling is intermittent and/or choppy? If so it may be that you're blocking the main thread when getting data from the web service, and you'd be able to solve that by doing that in a thread instead.

Comment: Any luck on how to solve this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this .....

```
    [self.YourScrollView setBouncesZoom:NO];
```

hope it will help you